# Change material icon color by using document.getElementById(item) not working

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

```js
if (document.getElementById(item).style.color == "grey") {
  document.getElementById(item).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<i class="material-icons" [ngStyle]="post.isLiked != null ? {'color': 'red'}: {'color': 'grey'}" id="{{i}}" (click)="LikePost(post.postType,post.postId,post.isLiked,i)">favorite</i>
```

I want to change color of material icon upon clicking on it.
Earlier it was working on chrome.Suddenly it stopped working.I'm not able to figure out the reason .Please help or what else can i use ??

Comment: This is my code :html:
<i class="material-icons" [ngStyle]="post.isLiked != null ? {'color': 'red'}: {'color': 'grey'}" id="{{i}}" (click)="LikePost(post.postType,post.postId,post.isLiked,i)">favorite</i>

typescript:

if(document.getElementById(item).style.color == "grey"){ 
   document.getElementById(item).style.color = "red";
}

Comment: Please add the code directly to your answer and, if possible in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I added your code to the question, please add the missing code for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="material-icons" [style.color]="post.isLiked != null ? 'red': 'grey'" [id]="i" (click)="LikePost(post.postType,post.postId,post.isLiked,i)">favorite</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using getElementById, you must put the id in quotes, like so:

```
let element = document.getElementById('my-element');
```

Also, if you're having trouble with these JavaScript assignments in the future, remember to use the console in the developer tools in your browser. You can type your code directly into the console, then type the variable name and press enter to see if the correct element is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the syntax but i used same id for 2 buttons - like as well as follow. That's why, it stopped working for one.My bad!